# Using two Dagger components in application class

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm trying to understand Dagger2. I've followed a few examples and using one component/module makes sense but adding a second confuses me. Am I not able to use more than one component in my application class?

Both Dagger components are highlighted red and say "Cannot resolve symbol..."

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

StorageComponent component;
ImageDownloaderComponent imageDownloaderComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    component = DaggerStorageComponent
            .builder()
            .storageModule(new StorageModule(this))
            .build();

    imageDownloaderComponent = DaggerImageDownloaderComponent
            .builder()
            .imageDownloaderModule(new ImageDownloaderModule(this))
            .build();

}

public StorageComponent getComponent() {
    return component;
}

public ImageDownloaderComponent getImageDownloaderComponent() {
    return this.imageDownloaderComponent;
}
}
```

Comment: You can  to use more than one component in my application class. Try to change return imageDownloaderComponent; and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting both pieces (SharedPrefs and Picasso) in one module and returned the component in my application class. Hope the wording makes sense.

```
@Module
public class StorageModule {
private final MyApplication application;

public StorageModule(MyApplication application) {
    this.application = application;
}

@Singleton
@Provides
SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences() {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
}

@Singleton
@Provides
ImageDownloader provideImageDownloader() {
    return new ImageDownloader(application);
}
}
```

MyApplication class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

StorageComponent component;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    component = DaggerStorageComponent
            .builder()
            .storageModule(new StorageModule(this))
            .build();

}

public StorageComponent getComponent() {
    return component;
}
}
```